# Node.js proxy request and encrypt it using AES

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, express, aes

What would be the easiest way in an Express app to code a route that proxies the request to another server and encrypts the response before sending it to the client (where it will be decrypted).
Is it possible to do it all using streams?

Comment: Since it'd be the obvious choice, why not just use HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, it is.  However, security is much more complicated than encrypting a stream with AES.  What are you trying to defend against? How will you distribute & update keys? How will you prevent MITM?

Comment: It's just something I'm testing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var request = require('request'),
    http = require('http'),
    crypto = require('crypto'),
    acceptor = http.createServer().listen(8089);

acceptor.on('request', function(r, s) {
    var ciph = crypto.createCipher('aes192', 'mypassword');

    // simple stream object to convert binary to string
    var Transform = require('stream').Transform;
    var BtoStr = new Transform({decodeStrings: false});
    BtoStr._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
       done(null, chunk.toString('base64'));
    };

    // get html from Goog, could be made more dynamic
    request('http://google.com').pipe(ciph).pipe(BtoStr).pipe(s);


    //  try encrypt & decrypt to verify it works, will print cleartext to stdout
    //var decrypt = crypto.createDecipher('aes192', 'mypassword');
    //request('http://google.com').pipe(ciph).pipe(decrypt).pipe(process.stdout);
})
```

Comment: Any advice on how to go about decrypting it in the browser?

Comment: Find client JS script that decrpyts common encodings.  this one maybe https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/  although I haven't used it..